# Ajax success data not appending when call function twice

Tags: php, ajax

I have a library in opencart to rotate the image and save in db.i have a rotate button which triggers ajax call and after rotating and saving, it returns the image and display in respective div.

On first call, it works fine, but if click again it rotates and save the image in DB but do not change the view in the front end.

HEREs my controller function:

```
public function rotateImage(){
    $img_path = $this->request->get['image_path'];
    $degree = $this->request->get['degree'];
    $this->load->model('tool/image');
    $new_image = $this->model_tool_image->rotate($img_path, $degree);
    return $new_image;
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
<script>
   $('.image-rotate').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   var image_path = $(this).attr('data-image-path');
   console.log(id);
   $("#image-"+id).empty();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'get',
       url: 'index.php?route=catalog/review/rotateImage&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image_path='+image_path+'&degree=90',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(html) {
           var image = "<a data-fancybox='' href='"+html+"' class='fancybox'><img id='r_image_"+id+"' src='"+html+"' alt='photo' width='100' /></a>";

           $("#image-"+id).html(image);
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Library:

```
public function rotate($file, $degree) {
    $old_image = $file;

    $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($file, 0, utf8_strrpos($file, '.')) . '-' . '600x600.' . $extension;

    $image = new Image(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    $image->rotate($degree);
    $image->save(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image);
    if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
        return HTTPS_CATALOG . 'image/' . $old_image;
    } else {
        return HTTP_CATALOG . 'image/' . $old_image;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but only on first call, after that only back-end data changes (image rotated successfully), but front view does not change.

If you need more detail plz commnet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...

Browser need new links to display always (without refreshing) so i just added a random number with image link in ajax success html data...

```
 var image = "<a data-fancybox='' href='"+html+"' class='fancybox'><img id='r_image_"+id+"' src='"+html+"?"+Math.random()+"' alt='photo' width='100' /></a>";
```

Also, I change the `return $new_image` of controller to return `jsono_encode` bcz ajax request need json response (may b i am wrong but this is what worked for me).